# find a string with a list of words, a char between them. and the final word can end with any string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of words:

```
const words = ["apple", "orange", "tomato"]

const str = "apple.orange.tomato.$COULD_$_BE_ANY_STRING_HERE"
```

I am looking for the regex to validate this string structure.

- the string cannot end with "."
- the string must contain at least one "." char
- the last string should support the "$" char

some patterns I've tried: `^((apple|orange|tomato)(\\.|$))*$` but it seems to allow the string to end with "." and to not contain a "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression to start with one of the words at least one followed by dot `^((apple|orange|tomato)\.)+?`, then optionally any letter or underscore `\w*?`, and not end with dot `[^\.]$`

```
^((apple|orange|tomato)\.)+?\w*?[^\.]$
```

[TEST](https://regex101.com/r/QVJ2ri/1)

Comment: It seems the last string cannot includes the "$" character. how can I add characters like "$"? ```"apple.orange.tomato.$COULD_BE_ANY_STRING_HERE$"```

Comment: You can with add the special character next to `\w` after pipe operator `|` inside a group `()`, like that `(\w|\$)*`

Comment: You can have a look at this test. https://regex101.com/r/mcNk52/1

Comment: `^((apple|orange|tomato)\.)+?(\w|\$|@)*?[^\.]$`